# Prometheus Query - Is there a limit on number range used in irate()?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

we are using an `irate()` function to check the rate of commands on a redis cluster in 2 minutes. The problem is, in 2 minutes, the difference is in millions and the graph is not showing up any values.

What type does prometheus use to compute the rate, is it int, long or double? Probably because of the type, the rate query isn't returning any values.

Comment: Are you sure it is not rather because of an interval too small ? computations are performed in double so it should not be an issue.

Comment: The same query works fine for other redis nodes in the cluster. It is just not working where the difference in metrics is too large.

Comment: Note that irate doesn't care about 2min or 3hours, it takes the 2 most recent data points. It is rate that uses the increase over the time range. Are you using the prometheus gui for testing your request ?

Comment: I sure that the 2 most recent data points have different values, checked in the prometheus UI, still rate() doesn't return anything for ranges from 1s to 24h.